# instert adsense ad after x number of posts

Tags: wordpress

I have Wordpress website and I want to implement Adsense ads into it.
my website is about job ads so it is not simple wordpress blog

I have 10 posts per page so i want to show ads after every 4 posts, how can I do this?
i tried this and did not work :

```
 if( $wp_query->current_post == 4 ) {

'my adsense code ';
       }
```

here is my loop code of posts

```
function themzy_get_ads_list_style( $args, $title )
{
global $themzy_theme;
    $html   =   '';
    $cats   =   '';
    $ads = new WP_Query( $args );
    if( $ads->have_posts() )
    {


        while( $ads->have_posts() ) 
        {  $ads->the_post();
            $pid = get_the_ID();
            $media  =    themzy_get_ad_images($pid);
            $img    =   $themzy_theme['default_related_image']['url'];
            if( count( $media ) > 0 )
            {
                foreach( $media as $m )
                {
                    $mid    =   '';
                    if ( isset( $m->ID ) )
                        $mid    =   $m->ID;
                    else
                        $mid    =   $m;

                    $image  = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $mid, 'themzy-ad-related');
                    $img    =   $image[0];
                    break;
                }
            }
            $cats = themzy_display_cats( $pid );
    $condition_html = '';
if( isset( $themzy_theme['allow_tax_condition'] ) && $themzy_theme['allow_tax_condition'] && get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_themzy_ad_condition', true ) != "" )
{           
    $condition_html = '<li>
                         <div class="custom-tooltip tooltip-effect-4">
                            <span class="tooltip-item"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></span>
                            <div class="tooltip-content"> 
                            <strong>'.__('Condition','themzy').'</strong>
                            <span class="label label-danger">
                            '.get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_themzy_ad_condition', true ).'
                            </span>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                      </li>';
}
$ad_type_html = '';
if( get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_themzy_ad_type', true ) != "" )
{           
$ad_type_html = '<li>
                         <div class="custom-tooltip tooltip-effect-4">
                            <span class="tooltip-item"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i></span>
                            <div class="tooltip-content"> <strong>'.__('Type','themzy').'</strong> <span class="label label-danger">'.get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_themzy_ad_type', true ).'</span> </div>
                         </div>
                      </li>';
}

$poster_contact =   '';
if( get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_themzy_poster_contact', true ) != "" && ( $themzy_theme['communication_mode'] == 'both' || $themzy_theme['communication_mode'] == 'phone' ) )
{
    $poster_contact =   ' <li>
                         <div class="custom-tooltip tooltip-effect-4">
                            <span class="tooltip-item"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></span>
                            <div class="tooltip-content">
                               <h4>'.__('Contact','themzy').'</h4>
                               '.get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_themzy_poster_contact', true ).' 
                            </div>
                         </div>


                      </li>';
}
    $timer_html = '';
    $bid_end_date   =   get_post_meta($pid, '_themzy_ad_bidding_date', true );
    if( $bid_end_date != "" &&  date('Y-m-d H:i:s') < $bid_end_date )
    {
        $timer_html .=  '<div class="listing-bidding">' . themzy_timer_html($bid_end_date, false) . '</div>';
    }

         $html  .=  $this->themzy_search_layout_list_2($pid, true, 'val');


        }

        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
```

I want to show ads after every 4 posts, is that possible  ? if yes how can i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

WordPress use globals, so you can use also $post and check the count of the post inside the template of your theme, like `index.php` or `archive.php`.

```
if ( ! is_single() && ($post === $posts[0] || $post === $posts[5]) ) {
    // Adsende source.
} // End if.
```

The example source above add the adsense content after the first and the 5th post.

Alternate you can use the the filter `the_content` to add them without changes of the theme template, via function in a plugin as example.

Comment: where i have to add the code you give me ? i put my whole code above where to put yours ?

Comment: Inside the template of the theme, where you will include the ad sense. Like the index.php or archive.php

Comment: not in while loop place ? whatever the place its ok ?because i insert code in loop while and didnt work

Comment: Oh yes, I side the loop. I know you have the knowledge, because it was also in the question.

Comment: Inside the template of the theme, where you will include the adsense source, see my comment and also inside the answer above.